# MersenneTwister repeated numbers

Tags: javascript, mersenne-twister

I have to create a random sequence of number using MersenneTwister (I can't change algorithm). Different calls to the generation algorithm always gives the same results after the first three attempts.
Here is the code:

```
var getRandomArray=function(length){
    var casuals=[];
    var mersenneTwister = new MersenneTwister(new Date().getTime()/2); //A SEED TEST
    while(casuals.length < length){
        var vmt= mersenneTwister.random();
        var newVal= Math.round( vmt*100);
        if(casuals.indexOf(newVal)===-1) 
            casuals.push(newVal);
    }
    //casuals.sort(function(a,b){return a-b;});//NUMERIC SORT
    return casuals;
};

var inputs1= getRandomArray(6);
var inputs2= getRandomArray(6);
//inputs1 AND inputs2 ARE ALWAYS THE SAME!
```

I tried changing different kind of seed but nothing changes.
I created here a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vcpjdo94/2/).

[Here](https://gist.github.com/banksean/300494) the algorithm I downloaded.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you mean you get the same values after calling getRandomArray three times? Or three calls to mersenneTwister.random?

Comment: None of them, after almost three calls to genRandom. You'll find it in the fiddle I created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you are using `new Date().getTime()`. The twister function finishes very quickly, to two successive calls to `new Date().getTime()` give the same value, thus the same seed.

If you add a different number, e.g. such as this:

- http://jsfiddle.net/vcpjdo94/3/

it works as expected.

The changes are:

```
$scope.genRandom=function(){
    $scope.inputs1= getRandomArray(6, 1);
    $scope.inputs2= getRandomArray(6, 2);
};
```

and:

```
var getRandomArray=function(length, add){
    var casuals=[];
    var mersenneTwister = new MersenneTwister(new Date().getTime()/2 + add);
...
}
```

i.e. addition of `add` parameter.

Comment: Thank'you, it solved! I didn't imagine that the two new Date().getTime() would be equal! I solved without further parameter this way:
var mersenneTwister = new Date().getTime()*(Math.random()*30);

Comment: ERRATA CORRIGE: 
var mersenneTwister = new MersenneTwister(new Date().getTime()*(Math.random()*30));